# Vuelidate simple required validation

Tags: vue.js

I try to do a simple validation with Vuelidate, for required, but I get an error, and I am not sure why!?

Thanks!

```
<form ref="form" @submit.stop.prevent>
<b-form-group>
    <b-form-input
    v-model="name"
    :state="name"
    v-model.trim="$v.name.$model"
    :class="{
    'is-invalid':$v.name.$error, 'is-valid':!$v.name.$invalid}"
    ></b-form-input>
</b-form-group>
<div class="valid-feedback">Ok!</div>
<div class="invalid-feedback">
    <span v-if="!$v.name.required">Not ok!</span>
</div>
</form>

import required from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

validations: {
    account_name: {
        required
    }
}
```

***Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

import { required } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

Required must have { } .